# Admob Interstitial ad (fullscreen) wont show

Tags: android, admob

I would like to show a fullscreen banner in my Android app.

In `onCreate` I call this function:

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    showInterstitial();
}
```

My function:

```
private void showInterstitial() {

    interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.ad_banner_id));
    interstitialAd.show();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Ad will load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

My App will crash with this message:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The ad unit ID must be set
>   on InterstitialAd before show is called.

But i set the ad id before show, or not?

Comment: have you added banner_ad_unit_id in resource like string.xml file?

Comment: yes this id will shown in log cat, if I give it out with Log.d
i put the id for testing directly: interstitialAd.setAdUnitId("xxxxx"); same error

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar it does not matter. Even a banner ad unit id will fetch an interstitial. Although it works, it is not recommended to do so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You did not call `loadAd()` for the interstitialAd. The interstitial ad should load before you can show it.

```
interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
```

also you should check if it is loaded before calling `show()`. It may not be immediately available and you may want to keep it loaded in advance before you call show.

```
if(mInterstitial.isLoaded()){
            mInterstitial.show();
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            mInterstitial.loadAd(adRequest); //optionally load again if you plan to show another one
        }
```

**Possible implementation (change it so suit your requirement)**

So basically the following can go in `onCreate()`

```
    interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.ad_banner_id));
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Ad will load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

and `showInterstitial()` becomes this

```
private void showInterstitial() {
        if(mInterstitial.isLoaded()){
                mInterstitial.show();
                //optionally load again if you plan to show another one later
                AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                mInterstitial.loadAd(adRequest); 
            }
    }
```

**NOTE:** call `showInterstitial()` when you want to display the interstitial ad. But, not immediately after calling `loadAd()`. It takes a few moments to load the intersitital ad and you may miss by a fraction of a second if the network is laggy or ad content is heavier than normal.

Also, here is the documentation for implementing [Admob Intersitials](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial?hl=en) the right way.

Comment: if i try this code, load() and isReady() will be red in android studio (Cannot resolve methods)

Comment: sorry it is loadAd and isLoaded ... i'll modify the answer. The above was for mopub but works in a similar fashion.

Comment: `AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();` put this and add it as the parameter.

Comment: okay, i did it like this. the Toast "Ad will load" will be shown. but no fullscreen banner

Comment: call the `showInterstitial()` somewhere and you will get the ad. But, not immediately after loading it. give it some time to load. use a click event somewhere for the time being to test.

Comment: yes, because i'm assuming you did it immediately after load. so it was not loaded and isLoaded() returned false. Hence show was not called.

Comment: BTW, showing the interstitial ad on app load is not advised and is against guidelines. You shold show it after some action or before exit. Basically at some logical point after the app is used.

Comment: okay, i put it now for testing as as action of a action bar item. and the banner will shown. BUT, i would like to show this banner, every time, if my main activity will shown. how can i realize this?

Comment: then show immediately after load automatically by overriding the `onAdLoaded()` method. You will need to create a new AdListener and then override this method. BUT, not recommended like i said earlier.

Comment: okay, than i will not do this. but if i will show this add after a click on a action bar item- first time the banner will shown. but if i got back to the main activity and touch again this bat item - not banner will shown. why?

Comment: I think you should try debugging sometimes. :)

Comment: I hope your initial question is now answered.

Comment: i debugging like a pro ! xD - but i do not understand this

Comment: try to check if the ad isLoaded when you return to the main screen again and click the view that loads the ad.

Answer (score 1):

add below perameters in `com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView`

```
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
```

---

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

verify that you have used below line in your parent layout

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

[just verify code](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class LoadAd {

    private final AdView ad;

    InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
    boolean isInterstitialShown = false;

    public LoadAd(Context con)
    {
        if (con.getClass().getName() == MainActivity.class.getName())
        {
            interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(con);
            interstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-8037008543529602/2054128571");

            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

            interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded()
                {
                    super.onAdLoaded();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdOpened()
                {
                    super.onAdOpened();
                    isInterstitialShown = true;
                }


                @Override
                public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode)
                {
                    super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);
                }
            });

        }

        ad = (AdView) ((Activity)con).findViewById(R.id.adView);
    }


    public void init()
    {
        if (ad != null)
        {
            AdRequest req = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            ad.loadAd(req);
        }
    }


    public void destroy()
    {
        if (ad != null)
        {
            ad.destroy();
        }
    }


    public boolean showInterstetial()
    {
        if (isInterstitialShown)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (interstitialAd != null)
        {
            if (interstitialAd.isLoaded())
            {
                interstitialAd.show();
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```